# quickly find a short string that isn't a substring in a given string

Tags: regex, string, perl, substring

I've been trying to serialize some data with a delimiter and ran into issues.

I'd like to be able to quickly find a string that isn't a substring of given string if it contains a delimiter, so that I can use that for a delimiter.

If I didn't care about size the quickest way to find it would be to check a character in the given string, and pick a different character, make a string of the given string's length of only that character.

There may be a way to do some sort of check, testing first the middle characters, then the middle of the first and last segment... but I didn't see a clear algorithm there.

My current idea, which is fairly quick but non optimal is
initialize a hash with all characters as keys and 0 as a count
Read string characters as bytes using the hash to count.

walk the keys finding the smallest number of characters. stopping immediately if I find one that has zero characters.

Use that number of characters plus one as the delimiter.

I believe that is O(n), though obviously non the shortest.  But the delimiter will always be no more than n/256 + 1 characters.

I could also try some sort of trie based construction, but I'm not quite sure how to implement that and thats 0(n^2) right?

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21896/algorithm-request-shortest-non-existing-substring-over-given-alphabet

may be helpful.

Comment: There are a few answers to a similar question [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21896/algorithm-request-shortest-non-existing-substring-over-given-alphabet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counting of characters method isn't sufficient because you're only talking about the current string.  The whole point of a delimiter is that in theory you're separating multiple strings, and therefore you'd need to count all of them.

I see two potential alternative solutions

1. Pick a delimiter and escape that delimiter in the strings.

   Can use [`URI::Escape`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Escape) to escape a specific character, say `&`, and use that as the delimiter.
2. Specify the size of your string before you send it.  That way you know exactly how many characters to pull.  Essentially [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) and [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html)

And because I'm already on the train of alternative solutions, might as well propose all of the other serialization modules out there: [`Comparison of Perl serialization modules`](http://blogs.perl.org/users/steven_haryanto/2010/09/comparison-of-perl-serialization-modules.html)

I like the theory behind a task like this, but rings too much like an [`XY Problem`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: No, but I have a standard delimiter for the module. I actually found a solution, but it was the theory that interested me.

Comment: Agreed, I can get lost for a day in the theory of a problem like that.  Took some level of self-control to not fall into that this time though  :)  Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Miller that your best bet is to pick a character and escape that in the text.

However, this is not what you asked, so I'll attempt to answer the question.

I take it these strings are long, so finding the delimiter is time-sensitive.

In straight Perl, the hash idea may well be as fast as you can get.  As a native C extension, you can do better.  I say this because my experience is that Perl array access is pretty slow for some reason, and this algorithm uses arrays to good effect:

```
int n_used_chars = 0;
int chars[256], loc_of_char[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) used_chars[i] = loc_of_char[i] = i;

for (int i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
  char c = string[i];
  int loc = loc_of_char[c];
  if (loc >= n_used_chars) {
    // Character c has not been used before. Swap it down to the used set.
    chars[loc] = chars[n_used_chars];
    loc_of_char[chars[loc]] = loc;
    chars[n_used_chars] = c;
    loc_of_chars[c] = n_used_chars++;
  }
}
// At this point chars[0..n_used_chars - 1] contains all the used chars.
// and chars[n_used_chars..255] contains the unused ones!
```

This will be O(n) and very fast in practice.

What if all the characters are used?  Then things get interesting...  There are 64K two-byte combinations.  We could use the trick above, and both arrays would be 64K. Initialization and memory would be expensive.  Would it be worthwhile?  Perhaps not.

If all characters are used, I would use a randomized approach: guess a delimiter and then scan the string to verify it's not contained.

How to make the guess in a prudent way?

Comment: Yeah, I want something O(n), that will always work (even if we have more then 64k data).